# Is there a String.IndexOf that takes a predicate?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to be able to say something like `myString.IndexOf(c => !Char.IsDigit(c))`, but I can't find any such method in the .NET framework.  Did I miss something?

The following works, but rolling my own seems a little tedious here:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "555ttt555";
        int nonDigitIndex = text.IndexOf(c => !Char.IsDigit(c));
        Console.WriteLine(nonDigitIndex);
    }
}

static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int IndexOf(this string self, Predicate<char> predicate)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < self.Length; ++index) {
            if (predicate(self[index])) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a regular expression?

Comment: +1 @Rune: certainly faster than enumerating a string

Comment: You already rolled it, the tedious part is taken care of :)

Comment: @IAbstract huh? What do you think a RegEx will do?

Comment: There is an IndexOfAny(char[]) but it would be pretty tedious to put in all non-digit chars :-).  Also Array has FindIndexOf() which takes a predicate, but calling ToArray() on the string would be heavy.  I like your extension method as is, personally.

Comment: Regexes are overkill for what I want to do.

Comment: @Carsten: I was mistaken on `RegEx`...not really using it enough, I was under the impression you could quickly and efficiently find indexes - but it doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: `Match m = Regex.Match(str, "[^0-9]"); int index = m.Success ? m.Index : -1;`, at least shorter than that query.

Comment: @SomeGuy enumerating a short string - like a user input field from a form - is almost certainly going to be faster than constructing a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN will show you all methods and extensions for a given type: [MSDN String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)

There is not currently an extension method specifically for `String` describing exactly what you have provided. As others have stated, rolling your own is not a bad choice since other options <strike>(besides `regex`)</strike> are not near as elegant.

**Edit**  I was mistaken about the efficiency of using `RegEx` to find indexes...

Comment: Are you saying that I did not answer the OPs question: *Is there a String.IndexOf that takes a predicate?*

Comment: no - you are right in this case sorry - I (as ever other here it seems) just took it as "please show me a short version"...

Answer (score 5):

You're not missing anything.  There is no `IndexOf` in the manner you're searching for in the framework.  The closest thing you could do without rolling your own would be

```
text
  .Select((c, index) => new { Char = c, Index = index })
  .Where(pair => !Char.IsDigit(pair.Char))
  .Select(pair => pair.Index)
  .FirstOrDefault(-1);
```

However that is not easy to follow and causes senseless allocations.  I'd much prefer to roll my own `IndexOf` in this case.

**EDIT** Whoops. Forgot that `FirstOrDefault` is a function I have hand rolled in my apps and is not a part of the standard LINQ libraries with this overload.

```
public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T defaultValue) {
  using (var enumerator = enmumerable.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      return enumerator.Current;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Here is a version that works without any custom extensions.  Note this is for example only, please don't put this in your app ;)

```
text
  .Select((c, index) => new { Char = c, Index = index })
  .Where(pair => !Char.IsDigit(pair.Char))
  .Select(pair => pair.Index)
  .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 1))
  .First();
```

Comment: +1 for: *I'd much prefer to roll my own IndexOf in this case.* The OPs usage is quite good IMHO

Comment: @IAbstract: +1 for your +1.  I like the extension method he has already.  I'd throw it in a common assembly of utility classes and call it done...

Answer (score 3):

Your current solution is better but *could* do something like ...

```
int c = myString.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).Count();
return (c == myString.Length) ? -1 : c;
```

Slightly shorter and somewhat fewer exception cases than the other proposals here, edited to show how to handle -1 case.  Note that the predicate is the inverse of the predicate in the question because we want to count how many characters ARE digits before we find a non-digit.

Comment: If the character isn't there, it produces 0. I see you've updated, but you should probably actually deal with that. Currently, there's no way to distinguish between "the first character matching the predicate is at index 0 in the string" and "no characters in the string match the predicate".

Comment: @dlev Note that my predicate is the opposite of the question; it *does* distinguish between those two cases.  If no characters in the string match the predicate it would return the length of the string, or now, with the edit it will return -1.

Comment: @antisanity: if the first character is a non-digit the sequence in `TakeWhile()` will be empty and Count() will be 0 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Array.FindIndex() provides a predicate overload but only works on char[]. So you could convert your string to a char array and use Array.FindIndex like so:

```
Array.FindIndex( text.ToCharArray(), 0, c => Char.IsDigit( c ) )
```

The performance penalty should be small as the string is probably stored in a char array anyway.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since `String` is an `IEnumerable<char>`, you can generalise your extension method to support almost any kind of collection (including strings) fairly easily:

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            return index;
        }
        ++index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```